# Nodejs backend ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I creaded this messy but somewhat functional backend server with nodejs:

```
var fs=require("fs");
var http = require('http');
var events=require("./public/events.json");
var evToAdd="";
var message = "";
var ledState= "0";
var os = require("os");
var url=require("url");
var emailTo="";
const querystring=require('querystring')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
function filterReq(request){
    console.log(request)
    if(request.indexOf("..")!=-1||request.indexOf("private")!=-1||request.indexOf("instaBio.js")!=-1)
    return true
    else
    return false
}

function getClientIP(req){
  return req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
}

function returnTimestanp(){
  var date_ob = new Date();
  var date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var year = date_ob.getFullYear();
  var hours = date_ob.getHours();
  var minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date_ob.getSeconds();
  var data=(new Date()).getTime();
  return "["+date.toString() +"/"+ month.toString() + "/" + year.toString()+" "+ hours.toString()+"h" +"-"+ minutes.toString() +"min"+"-"+ seconds.toString()+"s"+"]";
}
console.log("Server Started");
http.createServer(function (req,res){
    
    message = returnTimestanp() +" "+ getClientIP(req) + " requested: " + req.url + os.EOL;
  if(filterReq(req.url)){
    res.writeHead(403, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end("Acces forbidden");  
  }
  else if(req.url.indexOf(".json")!=-1){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
        res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public/events.json"));
  }
    else if(req.url.indexOf("css")!=-1){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
        res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public" + req.url));
  }


    if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let evToAdd = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        evToAdd += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        evToAdd=querystring.decode(evToAdd)
        console.log(evToAdd);
            if(evToAdd["psswd"]=="VPV9eMGNfC4EF2tq"){
    events[evToAdd["date"]][evToAdd["slot"]]["description"]=evToAdd["description"];
    events[evToAdd["date"]][evToAdd["slot"]]["type"]=evToAdd["type"];
    events[evToAdd["date"]][evToAdd["slot"]]["startHour"]=evToAdd["hour"];
    events[evToAdd["date"]][evToAdd["slot"]]["duration"]=evToAdd["duration"];
    fs.appendFile("./private/logEv.txt","User: "+evToAdd["user"]+" added: "+ JSON.stringify(evToAdd) + os.EOL, function(err, result) {
     if(err) console.log('error', err);
   });
    fs.writeFileSync("./public/events.json",JSON.stringify(events), function(err, result) {
     if(err) console.log('error', err);
   });
    }
        res.end('Event config was uploaded sucesfully to the server');
        
    });
    
}


  else if (fs.existsSync("./public"+req.url)){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  if(req.url=="/"){
    res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public/index.html"));
      
  }

  else{
    res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public"+req.url));
      
  }

  }
  else{
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end("The requested page was not found");
      
  }
  fs.appendFile('./private/log.txt', message, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Updated Log at: '+returnTimestanp());
});
}).listen(PORT);
```

and it works fine on my raspberry pi nodejs server, but when i try to host it on heroku i get this error:

```
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683363+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:292
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683364+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683365+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683365+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683366+00:00 app[web.1]: Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683366+00:00 app[web.1]:     at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:668:15)
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683367+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:788:7)
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683367+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:88:9)
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683367+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683367+00:00 app[web.1]:     at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:874:12)
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683368+00:00 app[web.1]:     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683368+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683369+00:00 app[web.1]:     at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:727:7)
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683369+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683369+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
2021-02-05T12:14:02.683369+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I've followed all the posibble fixes but i dont know what can I do next to solve this error.
As I sayed , it works on my nodejs server , but not on heroku.